# Data List Header Template causing 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a datalist that I want to repeat items and use the auto(row alternating) color for an application I am working on. I am trying to add a header template above the item template like so.

```
<table>
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" DataKeyField="num" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Type</th>
            <th>Item Price</th>
            <th>End(s) In</th>
        </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr>
            <td><a class="rolls2" href="ItemView.aspx?ItemName=<%# Eval("ItemName") %>&num=<%# Eval("num") %>"><%# Eval("ItemName") %></a></td>
            <td><%# Eval("ItemType")%></td>
            <td>$ <%# Eval("ItemPrice")%></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblExp" Text='<%# Bind("CreateDate") %>' runat="server" /></td>
            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DataList>
<table>
```

When I run this code I get a object not set to reference of the object and it points to `lblExp`.
If I remove the header the project runs sucessfully. Is there another way to simply add a Header to my table?

Comment: Why use an asp:Label and not a plain html label?

Comment: So I can change the value of it later on. In my code I take the date time currently stored there and use it as an expiration date with some datetime math.

Comment: Can you post the code from your `DataList1_ItemDataBound` method? That's the most likely culprit.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to diagnose this without seeing your code, but I would guess that your `DataList1_ItemDataBound` method is trying to find the `lblExp` control in the `e.Item` without checking the `e.Item.ItemType` first.

This event will be raised for every item in the list, including the header, and the header doesn't contain a control called `lblExp`.

You need to check the `ItemType` before processing the item:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
   switch (e.Item.ItemType)
   {
      case ListItemType.Item:
      case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
      case ListItemType.SelectedItem:
      case ListItemType.EditItem:
      {
         Label lblExp = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblExp");
         ...
      }
   }
}
```